# Razor view finding ViewModel without full path

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

Still new to ASP.NET, so forgive me for the simplicity of my question.

I'm writing a demo app in ASP.NET MVC Core 2. For my Views, I'm referencing the 
full path to the ViewModel, for example:

```
@model MyApp.ViewModels.ProductDetailViewModel
```

A solution that I'm following along with is using some voodoo whereby it's referencing its ViewModels without the full path:

```
@model ProductDetailViewModel
```

I don't mind using the full path, I'm just curious as to how the demo project is doing it. I'm not seeing any obvious clues as to how it's done.

Comment: It's in Web.config (check `Views/Web.config` too). There's an element that lists namespaces to include by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This likely is because the demo project will have added the namespace. It's done in the web.config, usually inside the `Views` folder. There will be a line like this:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
        <namespaces>
            <add namespace="MyApp.ViewModels" /> <!--- this line
```

For ASP.Net Core, the import is done in the `_ViewImports.cshtml` file which is in the `Views` folder. Add a line like this:

```
@using MyApp.ViewModels
```

Comment: For Core 2.0, I found it in the `Views/_ViewImports.cshtml` file.Thanks!

Comment: @DavidLiang Yeah, was just fixing it but got dragged into a meeting!